# Disable eval using tf.learn.Experiment

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

What's the best way to disable evaluation if I'm using tf.learn.Experiment?

I'm running this [model](https://github.com/googlegenomics/cloudml-examples) which constructs an experiment.

```
tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
        estimator=estimator,
        train_input_fn=train_input_fn,
        train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
        train_monitors=[export_monitor],
        eval_input_fn=eval_input_fn,
        eval_steps=FLAGS.num_eval_steps,
        eval_metrics=_create_evaluation_metrics(),
        min_eval_frequency=100)
```

To debug an issue with evaluation, I'd like to prevent evluation from running. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is going to depend on the method you invoke on `Experiment`. Presumably you are going to call train_and_evaluate, e.g., if `TF_CONFIG`'s task type is set to "master" (cf [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py#L135)).

In that case, you'll want to set `min_eval_frequency` to `0` or `None` (cf [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py#L453))

Comment: Thanks, although it looks like that would disable periodic evaluation during training but it looks like evaluation would still run once after training completes.

Comment: then just use the train() method